# Field type issue in Db entity query

Tags: c#, mapping, dbset

I have a simple query to a DBSet which is giving a typing error. When i debug it gives the following error: "The 'TranNumber' property on 'InventoryAdjustment' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'. ". Here is the code of the query:

```
var filter = DataContext.InventoryAdjustments.Where(x => x.RecStatus == 0 || x.RecStatus == 4).AsQueryable();
```

And the declaration of the field in the entity which is filtered:

```
[Column("TranNumber")]
 public int TransactionNumber { get; set; }
```

Since "filter" is an anonymous variable, i don't understand which is the mapping problem to result in that error.

Comment: What is the type for TranNumber in the actual database?

Comment: The type of the TranNumber column in the database is nvarchar. I thought it could be the problem but that entity is involved in other processes of the system without any problem.

Comment: That's likely your problem. It's trying to map a nvarchar field (string) to an integer field.

Comment: Ok. I'll check if that change doesn't affect other module of the system. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that your changes don't necessarily HAVE to be in the database. You could change your model instead so that TransactionNumber is a string rather than an int. That will also likely solve your query problem and then you can adjust the value accordingly in your C# code. Not a perfect solution in the long-run, but it's another approach.

Comment: You are right  ohiodoug. But in any case, i have to analyze both solutions because changing the model infrastructure in this case looks pretty messy too. Thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely. That's why I offered up the alternate solution -- it might have less consequences. I don't envy the day you are about to have. Good luck! =)